# How to convert the Prices on my ProductCard to another Currency in React JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api

I am working on a Multi-Currency ecommerce app in React JS. I have been able to successfully convert the price on the Product Detail page to Buyer's local Currency.

I am having problem converting the prices on the Products Mapped on the home page to local currency using the same method I used for the Product detail page.

This is the function for converting:

```
this.myFX = (item) => {
      const userCurrency = localStorage.getItem("myCurrency");
      fx.base = "USD";
      fx.rates = {
        AED: 3.6729,
        AFN: 77.050006,
        ALL: 100.85,
        AMD: 481.616228,
      ...
      };
      const result = fx(item.unit_price).from(item.currency).to(userCurrency);
      this.setState({
        convertedPrice: result.toFixed(2),
      });
    };
```

This is the code for mapping my products:

```
    <div className="card-body row">
                  {this.state.featured.map((item, i) => (
                    <Card
                      className="col-xl-3 col-sm-6"
                      style={{ width: "18rem" }}
                      key={i}
                    >
                      <Link to={`/product/${item.id}`}>
                        {" "}
                        <Card.Img variant="top" src={item.img1} />{" "}
                      </Link>
                      <Card.Body>
                        <Card.Title>{item.name}</Card.Title>
                        <Card.Text className="text-uppercase text-primary">
                          {item.category}
                        </Card.Text>
    
                        <Card.Title style={{ fontWeight: "500" }}>
                          Price: {this.state.convertedPrice}
                          
                        </Card.Title>
                      </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                  ))}
```

Please how best can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert prices in a map you could extract the conversion logic into a function that returns the value. Then use the new function in the map of results as well as the original place where the state is being set.

```
this.getConvertedPrice = (item) => {
  const userCurrency = localStorage.getItem("myCurrency");
  fx.base = "USD";
  fx.rates = {
    AED: 3.6729,
    AFN: 77.050006,
    ALL: 100.85,
    AMD: 481.616228,
  ...
  };
  return fx(item.unit_price).from(item.currency).to(userCurrency);
};

...

this.myFX = (item) => {
  const result = this.getConvertedPrice(item)
  this.setState({
    convertedPrice: result.toFixed(2),
  });
};

...

<Card.Title style={{ fontWeight: "500" }}>
  Price: {this.getConvertedPrice(item).toFixed(2)}
</Card.Title>
```

Comment: This is really working for me. But I have issue in passing the second parameter which is the Currency of that Particular product which will be my "from" currency. The products comes in multiple currency from individual . I did this but work for me: Price: ```{this.getConvertedPrices(product.unit_price, product.currency)}``` and ```this.getConvertedPrices = (item, currency) => {```